# How can I validate given time is greater then current time using Carbon on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, time, php-carbon

I wanted to validate time input formatted as `H:i:s` (e.g. "16:35:00") to be greater than current time.

```
$request->validate([
  'start_time' => 'required|after:now',
  'end_time' => 'required|after:start_time',
]);
```

Above code checks the date instead of time.

Comment: So this is not working? And which format you are sending time

Comment: Its not working and the format is 16:35:00 ( I don't know in H:m:s format )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the date to be compared to the actual input using `setDateFrom` (start in start, end in end) so only time remains checked with what you initially gives as a datetime:

```php
$request->validate([
  'start_time' => 'required|after:' . Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s'),
  'end_time' => 'required|after:start_time',
]);
```

Comment: Its not working it says 'The start time must be a date after 2021-05-26 13:28:06.' but the current time is '17:59:00'

Comment: I couldn't guess your input format, it would worth to precise it in the question.

Comment: In this case it's way much easier, you just need to precise the format for the start: `'required|after:' . Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s')`, answer edited.

Comment: Actually it works , I had messed up with my time zone :(

Answer (score 0):

However, it won't validate times from different days (eg `09:00 PM - 03:00 AM` the next day). `start_time` and `end_time`, in this case, should be provided as `HH:mm` but you can change it easily.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'start_time' => 'date_format:H:i',
    'end_time' => 'date_format:H:i|after:start_time',
]);
```